Revelation 22:16, referring to the angel Jesus sends
My daughter is in involved with Shincheonji church. The founder, Lee Man-hee, claims he's the angel in revelation 22:16. How can I convince my daughter that's not true. Please help me with this.
God bless, thank you,
Concerned father

One interpretation is that the 'messenger' is John himself who wrote the epistle.

wow thank you very much for your answers, you have giving me hoping in getting my daughter out of this coult , God Bless you ,

The New Testament warns Christians to beware of being deceived by some who will dazzle them with their claims and words and actions. The result will be luring them away from the biblical gospel of Jesus Christ to false gospels that will not save anybody. Here are some warnings from Jesus, including from the Book of Revelation:

"Not everyone that saith unto me, Lord, Lord, shall enter into the
kingdom of heaven; but he that doeth the will of my Father which is in
heaven. Many will say to me in that day, Lord, Lord, have we not
prophesied in thy name? and in thy name hath cast out devils? and in
thy name done many wonderful works? And then I will profess unto the,
I never knew you; depart from me, ye that work iniquity" Matthew
7:21-23 A.V.
"For there shall arise false Christs, and false prophets, and shall
shew great signs and wonders; insomuch that, were it possible, they
shall deceive the very elect." Matthew 24:24 A.V.

In case this leader is claiming to be a symbolic angel, and not a literal one, consider that in Revelation, Jesus had his angel foretell to the apostle John that he uses two witnesses on Earth (not angels) who have God-given power to prophesy as a witness against the nations but when their allocated time ends, God allows the satanic beast out of the bottomless pit to kill them. These are men who witness for Christ - not angels (Rev. 11:3-12). The only angelic witness to the world in Revelation is via an angel flying in midheaven, to declare the everlasting gospel to all nations, just before God's judgment culminates (Rev. 14:6-9).
The point in Revelation is that Jesus has, and sends, more than one angel. There are seven at the start, and throughout, for example. Any human claiming, "I am the angel in Revelation 22:16" has a great deal of explaining to do, to say why he is that particular angel in human form, and not any of the other angels. And, indeed, why none of the angels in Revelation are humans.
Finally, the apostle Paul warns Christians not to be easily fooled by anyone with a gospel message that has been perverted, not even by an angel:

"But though we, or an angel from heaven, preach any other gospel unto
you than that which we have preached unto you, let him be accursed."
Galatians 1:6-9 A.V.

Anyone beguiled by men claiming to be angels needs to see with their own eyes what Christ and the Apostles warn us of in that respect, in the Bible.

Revelation 22:16 (NIV)

“I, Jesus, have sent my angel to give you this testimony for the churches. I am the Root and the Offspring of David, and the bright Morning Star.”

While "angel" is singular, "churches" is plural. Therefore, if Mr Lee Man-hee is the angel in Revelation 22:16, he should travel to all churches globally,  not just be an angel of the Shincheonji church.


Rev 22:16 (BLB) - “I, Jesus, have sent My angel to give you this
testimony for the churches. I am the Root and the Offspring of David,
the bright Morning Star.”

The Chain of Revelation
The angel of Rev 22:16 is a direct reference back to the same messenger-angel of Rev 1:1, 2; the latter is what defines the "chain of revelation", viz:

Rev 1:1, 2 (BLB) - The revelation of Jesus Christ, which God gave Him
to show to His bond-servants what things it behooves to take place in
quickness. And He signified it through having sent His angel to His
servant, John, who testified to the word of God and to the testimony
of Jesus Christ, as much as he saw.

Note the clear sequence:

God gave the message to Jesus
Jesus gave the message to His angel
The angel gave the message to John
John gave the message to the church

Now, if Lee Man-hee believes he is the same angel as Jesus used to deliver the messages of the book of Revelation to John, then he must be about 2000 years old.  In fact, Lee Man-hee was born in 15 September 1931 and thus CANNOT be the angel that delivered the messages of Revelation to John 2000 years ago.
I also note a second reason that Jesus' angel cannot be Lee Man-hee - the angel was NOT designated to give the message to the churches - that person was John the Revelator, who again, is NOT Lee Man-hee.
APPENDIX - Extract about Lee Man-hee
The following is taken from  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lee_Man-hee

Lee was born on 15 September 1931 in Punggak-myeon, Cheongdo County,
North Gyeongsang Province (Keishōhoku-dō), Japanese Korea, Empire of
Japan. Before founding his own religious movement, he was a member of
the group known as Olive Tree and of another movement called the
Tabernacle Temple


Just pointing out this logic doesn't hold, if Lee Man-hee preexisted as an angel of the Lord Jesus 2000 years ago and incarnated in 1931

@Austin - but re-incarnation is opposed to Christian teaching.

Some people think Jesus was the Angel of the Lord prior to his incarnation. They don't consider that reincarnation.

@Austin - according to the NT in Revelation, Jesus is still the angel of the LORD.  Further, Jesus always claimed pre-existence.

I'm unfamiliar with where Jesus is referred to currently as the angel of the Lord in Revelation. Could you please point me to the right scriptural support for this?

@Austin - Rev 10 depicts an angel of the Lord which is a direct allusion to both Dan 10 and Dan 12.

We are warned in Hebrews 13:2 that angels will come and visit us as men. Whether actual flesh and blood is a mystery since many of those 'men' have suddenly disappeared. However they are not born as men from a woman, so being "incarnate" cannot apply. If Lee Man-Hee has a mother, he is no angel of God. If he has human ancestors, he is no angel of God.

@Biff - agreed.

@Biff - Your argument is valid. However, Mr Lee can claim that the Lord's spirit within him makes it difficult to discern any fabrication. The most effective way to prove a fault is to assume the hypothesis is true, and then demonstrate that the results do not align with the hypothesis.

@Vincent Wong Jesus had no human Fatherly lineage and angels have neither mother nor father genealogies. The Spirit of the Lord indwells all who believe. Jesus said, "you will know them by their fruits", so I suggest you start looking at his fruits and start building a case against him for your daughter with massive amounts of prayer and fasting.


How can I convince my daughter that's not true.

You can't. That's between her and God.
But there are things you can do.

Educate yourself. Learn more about the church that she is involved in. The more you understand, the better equipped you are to have healthy conversations with your daughter.

Maintain the relationship. For so many of us parents the challenge is to play the long game. I have a son in his thirties who for some years would have nothing to do with us because of some of our Christian beliefs. The relationship has improved, mostly because we hung in there and looked for practical ways to love him - helping him move into his first flat, giving him driving lessons, helping him with weekly groceries...

Have conversations, not debates. Although you can't convince her, you can talk with her. But do it in a gracious way. Don't aim to prove to her that she is wrong. Aim to create spaces where you and her can simply talk.


To take the example of your question, you shouldn't be asking us about the angel, you should be asking your daughter. And you should truly listen to her reply. You might be surprised. For example, maybe the reasons she goes to that church have nothing to do with Revelation 22. Maybe she gets other benefits, such as friendship or affirmation. And if the church's teaching on Revelation is important to her, it might still be for reasons that you and we don't yet understand, and our replies on the angel might miss the boat.
You should understand here that listening to her does not mean that you agree with her. I have had many conversations with Jehovah's Witness visitors over the years. I've learned that the best conversations we've had are where I say up front something like this: "Hi. I know enough to know that we will have different opinions, but I'm willing to listen respectfully to you so long as you treat me the same. Maybe that way we can both learn something!" I've let them talk first, then if I say something, I say it in terms of what I think, never pointing out to them why I think they are wrong. If they are listening, there's a chance they will connect with something I say; if I try to force my view down their throats, they will certainly not.

Find support for yourself. Who is a close friend that you can talk to privately and safely about your griefs and struggles? You need to guard yourself and maintain healthy life habits, so that you can be the best version of yourself for your daughter.

Pray. (As am I, while I write these notes.)



A brief comment about the angel of Revelation 22
My biblical answer to the question would be something like this:

First, John is having a series of visions of ultimate spiritual realities. Therefore everything needs to be understood spiritually. It's at least arguable that the angel is not even a real angel. The "angel" may simply be the way John experiences the transitions between each of the big picture scenes that Jesus reveals to him. The word angel in Greek means messenger. We need to be very careful with our interpretation of this word, just as we do with everything else in the book.

If we decide that the angel is real, then for me the main point is that he's an angel, not a human. Angels are angels. People are people. People becoming humans or vice versa is not part of the bible story at all.

Most importantly, the angel in Revelation is not Jesus. The angel is not the Messiah, not the Lamb of God, not the Rider on the white horse. The images of Jesus in Revelation are very clear, and they are different from the "angel" sections of the book. The angels are simply servants of God alongside us humans. In fact there are points where John is overwhelmed by the appearance of an angel, and the angel has to correct him. (See Revelation 19:10)


